# Angularjs http post to c# not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am completely new to coding so forgive me if this question is stupid.  I am trying to add a file upload button on a html page for the user to upload the file onto the server.  The project uses html, angularjs and the api is in c#.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>
</div>
```

My Angularjs function within the controller is:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
      var fd = new FormData();
      //Take the first selected file
      fd.append('file', files[0]);
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Users/x/Documents/api/FileController.cs',
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
      }).success(function(){alert('Success')}).error(function(){alert('Error')});
  };
```

In the FileController.cs file in asp.net I have a function:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

      if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path + FileName);
      }

      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The http post keeps showing an error.

**My questions are:**

- Is the format of this url correct? 
  url: '/Users/x/Documents/api/FileController.cs'
- Can a http post to a .cs file?
- Is there something missing from the function of the function written in c#?
- Is a page load required in c# to receive the post?

Comment: post the exception message

Comment: You need the action url, not the path like this "url: '/Users/x/Documents/api/FileController.cs',"
For example :
"http://localhost:8080/api/File"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't access the cs-file by post, but the method. So the url should end with /File:

```
/Users/x/Documents/api/File
```

First try to test using a get method which you can access directly through your browser. If that works, go on with your post

Comment: Actually just /File since Controller is not a part of routing